# Add existing value to an image URL

Tags: html, image, url

So im trying to add a `photo_reference` value that i get from a google maps api to image url that showing place's image  by `photo reference`. here's my code

`$("#poi-detail-gambar").html("<img src= "'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference="' + marker.poiData.photo_reference + "'&key=myKey />");`

but the image doesn't show up.

what did i do wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using template literals like this:

```
$("#poi-detail-gambar").html(`<img src= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=${marker.poiData.photo_reference}&key=myKey />`);
```

OR you can use it like this:

```
$("#poi-detail-gambar").html("<img src= 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference='" + marker.poiData.photo_reference + "&key=myKey />");
```

Comment: yes, im using the second one and it works, thanks